# I try `intval(6.02 * 100)`, the result is 602, but why the result of `intval(5.02 * 100)` is 501?

Tags: php

I try `intval(6.02 * 100)`,the result is 602。but why the result of `intval(5.02 * 100)` is 501?

Comment: Use `floatval` instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is a floating point math issue.  The following might help explain it:

```
ini_set('precision', 17);
echo (float)5.02;
```

> `5.0199999999999996`

```
echo 5.02 * 100;
```

> `501.99999999999994`

```
echo intval(501.99999999999994);
```

> `501`

More discussion on this topic:
[php intval() and floor() return value that is too low?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812815/php-intval-and-floor-return-value-that-is-too-low)